# How can I save SelectedFile path for the next time I run my project?

Tags: java, netbeans

```
String filepath;
chooser.showOpenDialog(this);
filepath = chooser.getSelectedFile().getPath();
```

How can I save the `filepath`?

Because the next time I run my project, I want to open the file automatically, but `filepath` is always being set to `" "` again.

I don't want to set a specific path to `filepath` cause it depends on users.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You could use Java's [Preferences](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/index.html?java/util/prefs/Preferences.html) API, that's its purpose:

```
Preferences node = Preferences.userRoot().node("MyApp");

// store the file path
node.put("filepath", filepath);

// retrieve the file path
filepath = node.get("filepath", "");
```